# Setting Route Parameters in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

frontend.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    //if lt IE 9
      script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js')
    // [if gte IE 9] <!
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js')
    // <![endif]
    script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', 
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/file1.js')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/file2.js')
  body
    #db(style='position:relative;')  
    #db2(style='position:relative;')  
    #pGC(style='height:800px; width:1000px; margin: 0 auto')
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var info = require('./routes/info');

var app = express();


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/info', info);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

info.js

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

   res.render('frontend');

    });
   module.exports= router;
```

When I add a parameter in the info.js  like this

```
 router.get('/:name',function (req,res) {
     res.render('frontend');
   }
```

now instead of looking for the static files in /javascripts/file1.js and /javascripts/file2.js

it is GET trans/javascriptsfile1.js and it returns a 404.

The files are located in public/javascripts/file1.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **frontend.jade**,

Change

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/file1.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/file2.js')
```

to

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/file1.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/file2.js')
```

The problem is that the javascript src is relative to rendered url (which is http://localhost/info). So, prepending it with '/' will make it start at the root url (http://localhost/) which express.static will serve the files in **public** folder.

Comment: Sorry I don't have my complete code listed here. I do in fact have module.exports = router;  in my info.js and a slash in front of info in app.js. Please look at my comment on the answer below. I guess that is my real issue

Comment: So, you should update the problem to state the real problem. Including the code that tries to get js/file1.js and js/file2.js would be useful to help inspect the problem.

Comment: okay I updated the question with more code and reflected the new problem

Answer (score 0):

When you call `app.use` your server will chain that function to every request. If you call `next()` in all your previous functions it'll eventually fall into this error function.

When you add the parameter, the request doesn't get caugh by the route and keep going through the middleware chain (and eventually to the error functions).